# Escape Comma values in fastercsv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am working on the csv generation. I am seperating values which are seperated by comma(,). If the value in a field contains comma, then it should not seperate the field in excel. So I want to put a escape character there. I am using FasterCsv. So how I can put a escape character. What is the escape character of fastercsv?

Answer (score 9):

Just quote every field (doublequotes by default) and commas inside of them are ignored:

```
CSV.generate(:col_sep=>',', :quote_char => '"') do |row|
    row << ["Quid, quid", "latinum dictum"]
    row << ["sit, altum", "viditur."]
end
=> "\"Quid, quid\",latinum dictum\n\"sit, altum\",viditur.\n"
```

Comment: it would be "videtur"

Answer (score 2):

If you have commas in your data, set a different column seperator with the :col_sep option. If you like your commas and can not live without them, set the data within quotation marks.

Comment: tab-separated values are a common alternate to comma-separated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the FasterCSV methods, this will be handled for you automatically!

Answer (score 0):

a creative way is to replace the real comma with a look-alike. This may be stupid, it all depends on your use case. It was ok for us - I think. I need to post this before I change my mind, lol

```
my_string.gsub(',','‚')
```

I'm not sure if it copy pasted this correctly, but you can create it on mac by holding `ALT(option) + ,`